# How to distinguish when user opened a game via FCM Push Notification and read its Custom Data or standard game icon click?

Tags: unity, firebase

I have successfully implemented a FCM within my game (for a chat system) and now I am trying to understand how can I open a specific chat scene when user clicks on FCM chat notification?

I successfully send `custom data` with the notification but now I have to be able to read it only when user clicked on that chat notification.

Game is developed in Unity and available both on iOS and Android.

Is there some out of the box functionality or I have to dig into core Android and iOS code and make magic?

I never done something similar to that so I am stuck.

Someone can help maybe?

Thank you

Comment: Is your question on how to navigate to the specific chat scene OR is your problem to only display content when the user clicks on the notification compared to navigating manually?

Comment: The first part you asked, how to navigate to specific scene based on the custom data received in notification. Both Android and iOS platform.

Comment: Since you control how to lay out your chats/ chat room/ messeges and you can include custom data already, include in the custom data a unique identificator for your chat you want to open. You can include a second identification for the line you want to display.

Comment: Of course, that is already done, but maybe my question was unclear. Let me explain  it more. I need to know when user clicked FCM notification so I can redirect them to correct scene. What is the correct way of checking in the code if user clicked on notification

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.notifications@1.0/manual/index.html scrolling down to `Save custom data and retrieve it when the user opens the app from the notification` basically something like that but with firebase?

Comment: Of course, but I cannot find anything with firebase. You have not work on anything like that?